# Dictionary keys as single list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary with keys as tuple and string. I want all the keys as a single list.

```
mydict={('google','yahoo'):['gmail','browsing'],'wix':['website'],('chrome','firefox'):['Browsers']}
KeysAsList=[]
for k in list(mydict.keys()):
    if type(k)==tuple:
        for item in k:
            KeysAsList.append(item)
    else:
        KeysAsList.append(k)`
print(KeysAsList)

output=['google', 'yahoo', 'wix', 'chrome', 'firefox']
```

I want to achieve the same output using list comprehension. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a key to a one-item list if it is not a tuple:

```
output = [i for k in mydict for i in (k if isinstance(k, tuple) else [k])]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this list comprehension:

```py
KeysAsList=[k for keys in mydict for k in (keys if isinstance(keys, tuple) else [keys])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had you only tuples of strings as keys, you could have used:

```py
output = [key for tup in mydict for key in tup]
```

But because of the `'wix'` as a key, you have to test whether the key is a tuple:

```py
output = [key for tup in mydict for key in (tup if isinstance(tup, tuple) else [tup])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really a list comprehension, but you could also use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) here to do the flattening after you normalise keys to all tuples. To make a singleton tuple we can use `(x,)`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> mydict={('google','yahoo'):['gmail','browsing'],'wix':['website'],('chrome','firefox'):['Browsers']}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(x if isinstance(x, tuple) else (x,) for x in mydict))
['google', 'yahoo', 'wix', 'chrome', 'firefox']
```